# How to modify my tikz drawing (Feynman diagram)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

I need to produce the following with tikz:

[image]

I have written:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm, varwidth=141mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

 \begin{document}


  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
  \begin{feynman}

    \node[shape=rectangle,fill=black,draw=black] (m) at (0, 0) {\rule{0.5cm}{0.5cm}};
    \vertex (a) at (225:2cm) {};
    \vertex (b) at (-45:2cm) {};
    \vertex (c) at (135:2cm) {};
    \vertex (d) at (45:2cm) {};
    

    \diagram*{
    (a) -- [photon,color=red] (m)
    -- [photon,color=red] (c),
    };
   \end{feynman}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

There are several issues. fill = white doesn't work to make inside the rectangle white. Also, I couldn't make the red lines horizontal and remove the right edge of the box.

Any help is appreciated.ti

Comment: Can you please try to find a title which describes a bit more closely what the actual problem is? In its current form, future `tikz-feynman` users with the same problem will have a hard time finding your posts if you use such generic titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm, varwidth=141mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{feynman}
    \coordinate (m);
    \vertex (a) at ( 225:2cm) {};% <<< changed y-coordinate
    \vertex (b) at ( -45:2cm) {};%<<< switched to polar: -60 deg, 1 cm radius
    \vertex (c) at (135:2cm) {};
    \vertex (d) at (45:2cm) {};
    \diagram* {
        (a) -- [photon,color=red] (m) % <<< funny bend
            -- [photon,color=red] (c),
        (b) -- [plain] (m) %<<< some color
            -- [plain] (d),
      };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{feynman}
    \node[rectangle, minimum size=1cm] (m) {};
    \draw[semithick] (m.north east) -| (m.south west) -- (m.south east);
    %
    \vertex (a) [left=of m.north west] {};
    \vertex (b) [left=of m.south west] {};
    \diagram*{
    (a) -- [photon,color=red] (m.north west),
    (b) -- [photon,color=red] (m.south west),
    };

 \end{feynman}
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

From comparison of code for second Feynman diagram with yours, you should observe:

- code for rectangle should be `\node[rectangle, draw, minimum size=1cm] (m) {};`, i e. you should remove `\rule` from node content, remove `fill=black`, and to options add size of node (`minimum size=1c`) and command `draw˛.
- that `photon` lines are straight, you need to set coordinates for vertex accordingly. In MWE I use relative positioning `left=of m.north west` and `left=of m.south west`
- that `photon` lines are straight ar drawn from `(a)` to
  `(m.north west)`, etc. See MWE.

Comment: @Samane, simple: not draw it ;-). I overlooked that it is not presented. Corrected now.